# Create an array of months with nested days between a date range

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to create an array of months that have nested arrays with all the days in that month between a date range in JavaScript with MomentJS.

aiming to achieve: if my date range was May 1st - June 3rd

Using this loop i can successfully build an array of days but i cannot split them into months..

```js
while (currentDate <= endDate) {
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
dates.push(new Date(currentDate));
```

This is pretty much what i want to achieve:

```js
[May - month name
1st May - date object for day
2nd May
3rd May
4th May
...]
June
[1st June
2nd June
3rd June]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your example is unclear: `May` is _inside_ an array, but `June` is _outside_ any array.

Comment: appologies - an array would contain all the months which would then contain all their days

[[may
1st
2nd
...]
[June
1st
2nd
]]

Comment: @roblawford please add the exact result you want to your question ... Your comment does not contain the "month name" And please make sure your example is valid syntax ...

Comment: dates[currentDate.getMonth()].push(currentDate) ?

Comment: @DannyHobo for the example this would create a sparse array with elements 0..3 being empty, furthermore, it won't add the month's name . and if you push `currentDate` all elements in the array will point to the very same instance of the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat).

```js
let start = new Date("05/01/2023");
let end = new Date("06/15/2023");
let arr = [];
let months = [];
const dayFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {day: "numeric"});
const monthFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {month: 'long'});

while (start <= end) { //get an array of date objects, one per day
  arr.push(new Date(start));
  start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
};

arr.forEach(function(date){ //get array of months
  let m = monthFormatter.formatToParts(date).find((o) => o.type == "month").value;
  if(!months.includes(m)){
    months.push(m);
  }
})

months.forEach(function(val,index){ //nest an array in each month
  months[index]=[val,[]];
});

months.forEach(function(month){
  arr.forEach(function(date){ //fill the nested arrays
    let m = monthFormatter.formatToParts(date).find((o) => o.type == "month").value;
    if(m === month[0]){
      let d = dayFormatter.formatToParts(date).find((o) => o.type == "day").value;
      month[1].push(`${ordinal(d)} ${m}`); //IF YOU WANT 1st May format
      //month[1].push(date); //IF YOU WANT THE DATE OBJECT INSTEAD
    }
  });
})
console.log(months)

function ordinal(number) {
  const pr = new Intl.PluralRules("en-US", { type: "ordinal" });
  const ordinals = {one:'st',two:'nd',few:'rd',many:'th',zero:'th',other:'th'}
  return `${number}${ordinals[pr.select(number)]}`;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bud - this kind of works, but you never get the first date in the array, always starts from from the 2nd date in the array...

Comment: And you also get an extra day on the end of the entire loop...

Comment: @roblawford just noticed and fixed that. Should be working now. Uncomment the code if you want the date object like you said in the original post. If it works pls accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain; vanilla JavaScript without any libraries to accomplish this. The `Intl` library provides an API for display time/date and number formats based on a locale.

```js
const
  monthFrmt = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'long' }),
  startDate = new Date('2023-05-01T00:00:00'), // May 1st
  endDate = new Date('2023-06-03T00:00:00'),   // June 3rd (inclusive)
  dateFormatterFn = (date) => `${ordinal(date.getDate())} ${monthFrmt.format(date)}`;

const main = () => {
  const dates = generateDates(startDate, endDate, dateFormatterFn);
  console.log(dates);
};

const generateDates = (startDate, endDate, dateFormatterFn) => {
  const results = [], currDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
  while (currDate <= endDate) {
    const key = monthFrmt.format(currDate);
    if (results[results.length - 1]?.key !== key) results.push({ key, values: [] });
    results[results.length - 1].values.push(dateFormatterFn(currDate));
    currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return results.map(Object.values);
}

const rules = new Intl.PluralRules('en', { type: 'ordinal' });
const suffixes = { one: 'st', two: 'nd', few: 'rd', other: 'th' };
const ordinal = (number) => `${number}${suffixes[rules.select(number)]}`;

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: While I like yours for for completeness, I like mine better bcs it's mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. A function for collecting the days between two days, and nother for grouping by month (you need year as well then).

```
const collectDays = (start, stop) => {
    let cursor_mut = start, out = [];

    while (cursor_mut <= stop) {
        cursor_mut.setDate(cursor_mut.getDate() + 1);
        out.push(new Date(cursor_mut));
    }

    if (start > stop) {
        return [out, true];
    } else {
        return [out, false];
    }
};


const groupDays = (dates) => {
    let grouped = {};
    
    for (let d of dates) {
        let key = JSON.stringify([d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()]);
        if (!grouped[key]) {
            grouped[key] = [];
        }
        grouped[key].push({ year: d.getFullYear(), month: d.getMonth(), day: d.getDate() });
    }
    
    return grouped;
};


let startDate = new Date();
let endDate = new Date();
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 90);
let outArray = [];
let result = collectDays(startDate, endDate, outArray);
console.log(result);
let groupedDates = groupDays(result[0]);
console.log(groupedDates);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpz43rog/1